# UIScrollView unresponsive after returning from FlipsideViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a written a simple example where I have a Utility Application project with one `UIScrollView` on it. When I click the info button to flip the screen and return the `UIScrollView` now is unresponsive. Not only that but I purposely placed the scroller in the Interface Builder in the upper left corner and then programmatically set it in the center. when I come back from the flipside its shifted up to the top left corner and unresponsive. why?

This is my `.h` file:

```
  #import "POCFlipsideViewController.h"

    @interface POCMainViewController : UIViewController <POCFlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    @end
```

This is my .m file

```
#import "POCMainViewController.h"

@interface POCMainViewController ()

@end

@implementation POCMainViewController


@synthesize scroller =_scroller;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

     [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(80.0f, 320.0f)];
     [_scroller setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 131, 80, 214)];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _scroller.delegate = self;
    _scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scroller.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(POCFlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}

@end
```

The rest is boiler plate straight from Xcode.[image]

Comment: just a note.. if i add this programmatically it will work..

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the culprit with UIScrollView is often Auto Layout. In Storyboard, highlight the view element under Main View Controller and then open the "Show the File Inspector" window in the right-hand column. Under "Interface Builder Document", deselect "Use Auto Layout" and see if that corrects your issue.

[image]